# ros_lib arduino IDE issue Rosserial

Tags: ros, arduino, robotino, ros-lib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
Im trying to use ros with the arduino, using the following rosserial tutorials.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup

After installing the Arduino IDE on Ubuntu 12.04 and copying the ros_lib folder into the sketchbook/libraries folder, I found that the IDE had not included these new files into the import library or the examples menu.

I tried copying the required header files for the hello world tutorial into the same folder as the hello world sketch but the compiler could not find them. I looked around and found that all the header files in the library need .cpp files or thats what i understand.
So basically i am unable to include any of these ros_lib files.

Can any one help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55663/ros_lib-arduino-ide-issue-rosserial/) by [samarth.rajan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3637/samarth.rajan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2013-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you install the ardunio ide into /usr/share. It seems that if you install in other places it doesn't contruct the links it needs.

---

Originally posted by [blueminerals](https://answers.ros.org/users/10691/blueminerals/) with karma: 16 on 2014-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0